# cannot copy .csv file from Windows to Linux server using php

Tags: php, linux, csv, copy

In php I can copy a .txt file from a location on my Windows OS  to ubuntu server but for some reason I cannot copy a .csv file. Does it possibly have something to do with Apparmor?
Here's my code which works 100% with .txt. However, if I try with a .csv file it doesn't work.

```
<?php
$fileName='Test.txt';
$location="C:\Users\...my location...\Local Store";
$Thispath = str_replace('\\', '/',$location).'/';
$ThisFile = $Thispath.$fileName; 

$dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/services/csv/';
copy($ThisFile, $dir.$fileName); 

if ( !file_exists($dir) ) {
 echo 'no file';
}
else{
 echo 'file exists';
 file_put_contents ($dir.'/hallo.txt', 'Goodbye File');
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the output you get?

Comment: State in the question how you are verifying if the csv file made it or not.

Comment: There is no .csv file when I use WinSCP and check in that directory - whereas when I copy the .txt file there & I check it's there.

Comment: Are the files truly named exactly the same thing other than the extension?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use backslashes to specify paths in PHP, ESPECIALLY when using double-quoted strings:

```
$foo = "This\is\a\path\not\a\string";
echo $foo;
```

produces

```
This\is\a\path
ot\a\string
```

Note how the `\n` in `\not` was interpreted as a newline char, not directory name starting with the letter `n`. PHP has **NO** idea what a path/directory construct is. It just sees strings. And since that double-quoted string contains a newline char, a newline char is what you get.

PHP will auto-convert `/` in a string-used-as-a-path to the local operating system's separator characters for you automatically. Just specify ALL your paths with `/` and let PHP handle the conversion:

```
$foo = "C:/foo/bar/baz";
```

If you INSIST on using backslashes, then properly escape them everywhere:

```
$foo = "C:\\foo\\bar\\baz";
```

to prevent them from be interpreted as escapes/metachars.

Comment: So I shouldn't use the str_replace?

Comment: if your path contained a `\n`, then the `\n` will be GONE from the string, because it'll have been parsed as a newline char. Now your `klm\nop` two-level directory will be a single `klm[newline]op` directory which doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm trying to implement what you suggest, but howcome it works for .txt files despite the backslashes?

Comment: I've tested & it works (thanks very much) - on condition I put content in, i.e. if I just copy & don't use the line file_put_contents it doesn't work.... ?

Comment: I've discovered that it doesn't actually work because file_get_contents isn't working...